# "pg_ctl: could not find postgres program executable" but only on startup?

Tags: windows-server-2003, service, postgresql

I'm having a strange new issue with PostgreSQL.  After the last two reboots it hasn't started properly, and that was the error in the log (it occurs early enough in the startup process to not say anything in Postgres' own logs.)  Starting it manually via the Services window worked fine both times.  Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try PostgreSQL 9.0.